# How to make a derived query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I was trying to make a query that allows me to see how many books every author wrote in French and English. Well I know that I have to do it with two derived queries but I didn't figure out how to connect them. The result I get after running it makes no sense...

There might be a much simpler way to do it but after trying this for hours I was not able to figure it out.

```
SELECT tblBooks.fldAuthor, fldFrench, fldEnglish
FROM tblBooks, (
        SELECT fldAuthor, COUNT(*) AS fldFrench
        FROM tblBooks
        WHERE fldLanguage = 'FR'
        GROUP BY fldAuthor
    ) AS French
Join
    (
        SELECT fldAuthor, COUNT(*) AS fldEnglish
        FROM tblBooks
        WHERE fldLanguage = 'EN'
        GROUP BY fldAuthor
    ) AS English
ON French.fldAuthor = English.fldAuthor;
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I don't know if I can Import my Database but here is the base:

```
CREATE TABLE tblBooks(
    fldAuthor   CHAR(30),
    fldTitle    CHAR(30),
    fldLanguage CHAR(2));


INSERT INTO tblbooks
VALUES('Markus', 'abc', 'EN');

INSERT INTO tblbooks
VALUES('Santa', 'dfs', 'EN');

INSERT INTO tblbooks
VALUES('Santa', 'bcd', 'EN');

INSERT INTO tblbooks
VALUES('Santa', 'fge', 'FR');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example was done in SQL Server but the concept will translate the same to MySQL.

```
--create a populated temp table
select *
into #tblBooks
from
(
  values
  ('Book 1', 'Charlie Brown', 'EN'),
  ('Book 2', 'Mickey Mouse', 'EN'),
  ('Livre 3', 'Jacques Clouseau', 'FR'),
  ('Book 4', 'Charlie Brown', 'EN'),
  ('Livre 5', 'Jacques Clouseau', 'FR'),
  ('Book 6', 'Charlie Brown', 'EN'),
  ('Livre 7', 'Pepe le Pew', 'FR'),
  ('Book 8', 'Jacques Clouseau', 'EN'),
  ('Book 9', 'Charlie Brown', 'EN'),
  ('Livre 10', 'Charlie Brown', 'FR')
) d (fldBookName, fldAuthor, fldLanguage);

--look at data in temp table
select * from #tblBooks;

--calculate number of French books and number of English books for each author
select
fldAuthor,
fldFrench = sum(case fldLanguage when 'FR' then 1 else 0 end),
fldEnglish = sum(case fldLanguage when 'EN' then 1 else 0 end)
from #tblBooks
group by
fldAuthor;
```

Here are the results -
contents of #tblBooks:
[image]

summary:
[image]

If MySQL has `IF` it would also be possible to replace the `CASE` statement with that to shorten it up a bit.

The above version is the way I would go about solving this because it is very concise.  However, here is a version (also done in SQL Server) that uses derived tables to achieve the same summary result as shown above:

```
select distinct
b.fldAuthor,
fldFrench = isnull(f.fldFrench, 0), --case when f.fldFrench is null then 0 else f.fldFrench end,
fldEnglish = isnull(e.fldEnglish, 0) --case when e.fldEnglish is null then 0 else e.fldEnglish end
from #tblBooks b
left outer join
  (
    select fldAuthor, fldFrench = count(1)
    from #tblBooks
    where fldLanguage = 'FR'
    group by fldAuthor
  ) f on b.fldAuthor = f.fldAuthor
left outer join
  (
    select fldAuthor, fldEnglish = count(1)
    from #tblBooks
    where fldLanguage = 'EN'
    group by fldAuthor
  ) e on b.fldAuthor = e.fldAuthor;
```

Not sure if MySQL has an equivalent for `ISNULL`, if not then just replace with the `CASE` statement as shown above with an inline comment.  The purpose of this is to display a zero rather than NULL when no books are found for a given author in the given language.